# 1004 Error when trying to copy and send destination with Set two range objects

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all  Receiving an '1004' copy method of range class failed when attempting to use the copy function and send to another set range.  Any ideas why this might be happening?  Code below (**Note: I have not gotten to close the loop yet.  I was building the set up and ran into this error.  I didn't remove the loop because i'm simply debugging this issue**):

```
Sub GetOiData(cmeDataBook As Workbook, oiSheet As Worksheet)
'Loops through OI data sheets and transfers OI data by puts and calls cleanly
Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
Dim startMonthLocation As Range, startRangePutStrike As Range, startRangeCallStrike As Range, monthFutureVolumeFinder As Range
Dim monthConverted As String, callOpt As String, putOpt As String, assetType As String
Dim continue As Boolean

callOpt = " Calls"
putOpt = " Puts"
assetType = oiSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
continue = True
Set dataSheet = cmeDataBook.Sheets(GetDataSheetDesignation(assetType))
Set startMonthLocation = oiSheet.Cells(2, 2)
dataSheet.Activate

'Iterates through entire Oi data sheet incrementally
Do While continue = True

    'Finds total volume for the month and then sets monthConverted to prepare for oi process
    monthConverted = MonthCode(oiSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value)
    Set monthFutureVolumeFinder = dataSheet.Columns(1).Find(Trim(monthConverted))
    monthFutureVolumeFinder.Offset(0, 4).Copy (startMonthLocation.Offset(1, 0))

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Appears to have had incorrect syntax.

**Changed** 
`monthFutureVolumeFinder.Offset(0,4).Copy (statMonthLocation.Offset(1,0))` **to**

`monthFutureVolumeFinder.Offset(0,4).Copy Destination:=startMonthLocation.Offset(1,0)`

**Full code below:**

```
Sub GetOiData(cmeDataBook As Workbook, oiSheet As Worksheet)
'Loops through OI data sheets and transfers OI data by puts and calls cleanly

    Dim oiDataSheetInCmeBook As Worksheet
    Dim startMonthLocation As Range, startRangePutStrike As Range, startRangeCallStrike As Range, monthFutureVolumeFinder As Range, monthCallLocationFinder As Range, monthPutLocationFinder As Range
    Dim monthNameConverted As String, callOpt As String, putOpt As String, assetType As String
    Dim continue As Boolean

    callOpt = " Calls"
    putOpt = " Puts"
    assetType = oiSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value
    continue = True
    Set oiDataSheetInCmeBook = cmeDataBook.Sheets(GetDataSheetDesignation(assetType))

    'Sets ranges for initial iteration through specific OI sheet
    Set startMonthLocation = oiSheet.Cells(2, 2)
    Set startRangePutStrike = oiSheet.Cells(5, 1)
    Set startRangeCallStrike = oiSheet.Cells(5, 3)
    dataSheet.Activate

    'Iterates through entire Oi data sheet incrementally
    Do While continue = True

        'Finds total volume for the month and then sets monthConverted to prepare for oi process
        monthNameConverted = MonthCode(oiSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value)
        Set monthFutureVolumeFinder = oiDataSheetInCmeBook.Columns(1).Find(Trim(monthConverted))
        monthFutureVolumeFinder.Offset(0, 4).Copy Destination:=startMonthLocation.Offset(1, 0)

        Set monthPutLocationFinder = oiDataSheetInCmeBook.Columns(1).Find(Trim(monthConverted & putOpt))

    Loop

End Sub
```